# How to apply cascading in below scenario using JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, jquery, jsom

I Have a requirement to leverage Cascading in a little tricky way and which is where i need help. The Project I am working on, there is a Custom list called 'Company List', please see below screenshot. Title column shows names of the relevant subsites under root, these all entries are manually entered by a user. The list resides at root site and which is where it will be controlled to add, edit and delete entries.

[image]

I have then created a site column called **'Relevant Company'** of type lookup to the Company Column in Company List.

Below is the Screenshot of the Test Site 1 and which is where i have created a library as Acquisition in which relevant company is added as an existing site column.

[image]

So the challenge here is, when someone uploads a document to the Acquisition library on Test Site 1, the users only want to see Choices that are relevant to Test Site 1 title column entry in Company List if they are working on Test Site 1 which are: AMS Insurance Inc and AIMS Health Care LLC,other choices must be hidden.This should be dynamic in nature so whenever a user adds a new company info in the Company List for Test Site 1 then that should become available in the drop-down on Acquisition's Relevant Company drop-down (under Test Site 1 subsite).

I have worked on cascading where the list would reside at the same site level and it makes the job easier but not sure how I would achieve it here since Site Column is in place. I have a site template based on which the sub sites will be created and the code will go part of the template on Acquisition library.Logically maybe we could read the site name on page load and match it with the entry in Company List and do show or hide, not sure if I am right but if someone can help me out with the JS/JQ Code as i am working with SharePoint online, thanks in advance.

[image]

Note: I am also open if adding another metadata column to the Acquisition library makes it easier, for example Title column from Company List. Thanks.